# Файлы .mdx в Linux

Tags: linux, mount, iso

Имеется файл с разрешением .mdx. На форумах вычитал что, чтобы его открыть, нужно конвертировать в .iso программой iat. Запускаю конвертацию, но она не работает, в консоли пишет сообщение и висит так до бесконечности. В чем проблема? Не понимаю, может есть еще способы открыть такой файл?

`$ iat MB.mdx MB.iso`

```
Iso9660 Analyzer Tool v0.1.3 by Salvatore Santagati
Licensed under GPL v2 or later
```

`$ file MB.mdx`

```
MB.mdx: MED_Song
```

Выполнив команду: `$ strace iat MB.mdx MB.iso` я получил сотни строк в секунду такого плана:

`lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(3, 73728, SEEK_SET)               = 73728
read(3, ".\361\3118\243\2755\253\262u\306\332\263\245\272\376\325\337\264?\361u\321/\346\236\177\250\362K\\\341"..., 1790) = 1790
read(3, "$\325k\346\315G\316\334#_\367\346\253\270\343\215\357\313W\277\362+\271\347\221\217\277\350\272\366%d"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(3, 73728, SEEK_SET)               = 73728
read(3, ".\361\3118\243\2755\253\262u\306\332\263\245\272\376\325\337\264?\361u\321/\346\236\177\250\362K\\\341"..., 1791) = 1791
read(3, "\325k\346\315G\316\334#_\367\346\253\270\343\215\357\313W\277\362+\271\347\221\217\277\350\272\366%dv"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(3, 73728, SEEK_SET)               = 73728
read(3, ".\361\3118\243\2755\253\262u\306\332\263\245\272\376\325\337\264?\361u\321/\346\236\177\250\362K\\\341"..., 1792) = 1792
read(3, "k\346\315G\316\334#_\367\346\253\270\343\215\357\313W\277\362+\271\347\221\217\277\350\272\366%dv\237"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(3, 73728, SEEK_SET)               = 73728
read(3, ".\361\3118\243\2755\253\262u\306\332\263\245\272\376\325\337\264?\361u\321/\346\236\177\250\362K\\\341"..., 1793) = 1793
read(3, "\346\315G\316\334#_\367\346\253\270\343\215\357\313W\277\362+\271\347\221\217\277\350\272\366%dv\237x"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET^C)`

Comment: Навряд ли Вы успели подождать до бесконечности. Во первых, я бы запустил конвертацию и отдельно посмотрел, а iso создался? размер увеличивается?

Comment: я ждал минут 30. Ничего не происходит и файл iso не создается.

Comment: тогда только запуск через отладчик/strace/ltrace и смотреть, что происходит. Может к файлу просто нет доступа

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. приложите, пожалуйста, вывод `$ file MB.mdx`

Answer (score 0):

А пропробуй просто смонтировать со смещением:

```
mount -o loop,offset=64 image.mdx /mnt/cdrom/
```

Если не помогло, то похоже там гибридный раздел.
Также можно попробовать вручную указать тип диска. Чаще всего это udf или iso9660

```
mount -t udf -o loop,offset=64 image.mdx /mnt/cdrom/

mount -t iso9660 -o loop,offset=64 image.mdx /mnt/cdrom/
```

Также формат поддерживает сжатие. Если данные сжаты - то нужноконвертировать в iso.   Просто так не подключится.

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom
$ sudo modprobe loop # в убунтах обычно не нужно
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=64 "Alter Ego +3 Manuel CD.mdx" /mnt/cdrom/
mount: /mnt/cdrom: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
$ ls /mnt/cdrom/
AlterEgo+3.exe  AlterEgo+3.swf  autorun.inf  data  Licence_PC.txt  lisez-moi_PC.txt  modules  Read-me_PC.txt  ressources  swf
$ mount
...
Alter Ego +3 Manuel CD.mdx on /mnt/cdrom type iso9660 (ro,relatime,norock,check=r,map=n,blocksize=2048)
```

Comment: В ответ получил ошибку:

`NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop8': Недопустимый аргумент
The device '/dev/loop8' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?`

Comment: Если монтировать, то надо использовать `guestmount`

Comment: @0andriy зачем? там же исошка в контейнере

Comment: @boomuo а с -t udf?

Comment: @eri mount: /home/vlad/MB: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop8, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Comment: @boomuo наверное сжатый. потому и iat не видит. попробуй откусить заголовок и попробовать определить тип архива. ну или выкладывай файл - посмотрю

Comment: @eri, очевидно, чтобы не лазать туда root’ом.

Comment: @0andriy на сколько я знаю guestmount это     Access and modify virtual machine disk image. Возможно Вы путаете с Fuse

Comment: @eri, нет, не путаю. Он основан на FUSE.

Comment: @0andriy надо посмотреть умеет ли он такие контейнеры открывать. Простой mdx открывается просто смещением, а что там за сжатие в википедии не написанно) да и на торентах два мдх на весь трекер, а винду ставить лень...

Comment: @eri тут вот ссылка на торрент https://vsetor.org/1186-mount-and-blade-warband.html